# Probability and Stats

Tags: probability, statistics

I need some help with the following question:

In the game of "odd man out" each player tosses a fair coin. If all the coins turn up the same except for one, the player tossing the different coin is declared the odd man out and is eliminated from the contest. Suppose that three people are playing. What is the probability that someone will be eliminated on the first round? Hint: use the complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. There are only two possibilities - (1) all three same with probability 2/8 and (2) one H/T, other two T/H, with probability (1-2/8)=6/8 using compliments.

So someone will be eliminated w.p. 3/4.

---

In fact, if there were $n$ coins, it is $n/2^{n-1}$ and you can calculate it thus.

The following are the possibilities in which someone will be eliminated -

*Odd man has H*:
$\{(\color{red}H,T,T,...,T), (T,\color{red}H,T,...,T),..., (T,T,T,...,\color{red}H)\}$

*Odd man has T*:
$\{(\color{red}T,H,H,...,H), (H,\color{red}T,H,...,H),..., (H,H,H,...,\color{red}T)\}$

Each set has $n$ elements, so the probability is ${2n}/{2^n}=n/2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Hey, I got it! I just drew the table for the outcomes of three coin tosses and got 6/8.

Comment: Yeah - it's easy to get into and becomes very interesting. Probability theory, one of the best branches of maths! Good luck Adib.